# why couldnot I install "seaborn" and "pandas" in ubuntu?

Tags: python, pandas, pip, seaborn, miniconda

in my code, there are

```
import seaborn
```

and they give me

```
no module named seaborn
```

when I use

```
pip install seaborn
```

it gives me **Requirement already satisfied** but I still couldnot import *seaborn* so I use `pip3 install seaborn`,it reports so many errors as follow:

```
 Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/79/f236ab1cfde94bac03d7b58f3f2ab0b1cc71d6a8bda3b25ce370a9fe4ab1/pandas-1.0.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-c8lrjdqb/pandas/setup.py", line 42
        f"numpy >= {min_numpy_ver}",
                                  ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-c8lrjdqb/pandas/
```

I don't know how to solve this, and I have upgraded my setuptools like:`pip install --upgrade setuptools` and also `pip3 install --upgrade setuptools`

and also I have tried `conda install seaborn` it looks like work well but when I run my code, it still told me `no module name seaborn`
so how could I install seaborn on my ubuntu?

I have checked my python version by `python --version` it is *python3.8*.

Same problem also happened with **install pandas***.

Comment: Then do `pip3 install --upgrade setuptools` and then `pip3 install seaborn`

Comment: yep I have tried pip3 install --upgrade setuptools and it couldnot work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both python2 and python3 come shipped along with Ubuntu, so installing packages with just pip might be your issue as that is the default package manager for python 2.

Try the following in your terminal:

`$ python3 -m pip list | grep seaborn`

If you dont get an output then this shows you that seaborn hasn't been installed via pip linked to your python3 interpreter.

It is good practice to install packages for your interpreter specifically as follows:

`$ python3 -m pip install <insert name of package here>`

Finally to check that the package has installed correctly launch the python3 interpreter within your terminal and try and import the package e.g.

`$ python3`

`>>> import seaborn as sns`

Most of the packages for your python distribution should be in the following directory:

`$ cd /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages`

The above are just a few pointers to get you started, hope that helped!

Comment: hey when I want to install "flask" I met with a new problem. I use ```python3 -m pip list | grep flask```  to check, there is nothing. however when I use ```python3 -m pip install flask``` it tells me ```requierements already satisfied```.